# Angular HTTPClient get Test API

Tags: angular, http, mean

I have written a simple Method, to retrieve the json res object from a url api endpoint. I want to get that output and put it in some

object in a HTML template...

Here is my function from the api endpoint that returns my json:
I can call it with a date range parameter string between "." and id.

```
exports.someFnct = function(req, res) {
    //http://localhost:6000/link/Coll/2018-06-04T13:01:02.2018-06-04T15:18:45.11
    demo_id=req.params.demo_id;
    start = req.params.start;
    end = req.params.end;

    FP.findById(demo_id)
    .then(fps => {
            startts = +new Date(start)
            endts = +new Date(end)
            TSarray = []
            for (let doc of fps["someArray"]) {
                ts = + new Date(doc["Timestamp"])
                if ((ts >= startts) && (ts <= endts)){
                    TSarray.push(doc)                                                   
                }               
            }
            res.json(TSarray);
            //return TSarray;
        }
    ).catch(e => { console.log(e); res.send(e);});
}
```

I run the server, it works as expected and returns me an array of some documents in the browser.
Now, I have another angular project set up with a component where I want to test some basic Http.get call and I want to display the json objects / fields in some html template component.

My Angular component is like this:

```
export class HttptestComponent implements OnInit {

  fp: FPro[]

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  loadFPro() {
    return this.http.get(`http://localhost:6000/link/Coll/2018-06-01T11:00:45.2018-06-01T17:15:45.29`)
    .map(res => res.json() as FPro[])
    .subscribe(res => this.fp = res);
  }


}

interface FPro {
  Timestamp: Date, 
  name: string
}
```

My template that should display the data is:

```
  <div class="row">  
  <button class="btn btn-danger float-xl-right mt-1" 
    (click) = "loadFPro()">  Call HTTPService
  </button>  
  </div>

<div *ngIf="fp">
    <h2>Retrieved Data is ready!</h2>
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let pro of fp">
        {{pro}}
      {{pro.Timestamp}},
      {{pro.name}}
      </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

However, when I click the button, nothing is displayed, why? Do I have to use a special return value for the res.json, or does the Http Client just "grab" the response object from the link, whatever this is? And how can I adapt it so that I dont need some fp interface to get the object, and make it more general, like with "any"?

Answer (score 1):

you should use `map` operator inside `pipe`
so your function will be like

```
  loadFPro() {
    return this.http.get(`http://localhost:6000/link/Coll/2018-06-01T11:00:45.2018-06-01T17:15:45.29`)
    .pipe(map(res => res.json() as FPro[]))
    .subscribe(res => this.fp = res);
  }
```

also you dont have to do `res.json()` httpClient will do that for you, but what you can do is:

```
  loadFPro(): FPro[] {
    return this.http.get(`http://localhost:6000/link/Coll/2018-06-01T11:00:45.2018-06-01T17:15:45.29`)
    .subscribe(res => this.fp = res);
  }
```

Comment: thanks thats useful, but my problem was actually something different, I had to use CORS library for Cross-Origin Resource Sharing, because I used another port and url for my backend that was different from my angular app port..